# Support library 26 - DialogFragment, CursorAdaptor missing

Tags: android, android-support-library

When I updated Android support library 26, it can't find classes like DialogFragment, CursorAdaptor etc. any more. Does that mean that I should use `android.widget.CursorAdapter` and `android.app.DialogFragment` instead?

Comment: `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` [definitely exists](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html). `android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter` [should also exist](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html).

Comment: Any idea what the problem might be? Am I missing some library? I've included support-core-utils:26.0.1, support-core-ui:26.0.1, support-fragment:26.0.1 and support-compat:26.0.1.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it can't find classes"? `support-fragment` and `support-compat` should cover those two classes AFAIK. Also, try creating a scrap project in Android Studio and see if those classes show up in the scrap project.

Comment: If I try to include one of the classes, and I start to write ...v4.app. then I can't see the DialogFragment in the list of available classes. Only ActivityCompat and other classes. But now it seems to work. I included only "appcompat-v7:26.0.1" and then I can find the classes. So I guess that solves the problem. :)